# Rolling a die 60,000 times using if-else-if

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm new to javascript and am facing trouble with the following problem.

Simulate rolling a die 60,000 times and display the frequency with which each face of the die finishes uppermost.

Use 6 variables to capture the frequencies and a 6-way if-else-if control structure need in the loop to increment them appropriately.

I know that I have to create an empty array which includes 6 variables and I have started the first iteration with 1.
What I don't understand is how to use the if-else-if statement to work through the 60000 iterations.

```
var array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var i = 1;
```

Comment: Why is using `if-else` a requirement? It doesn't really make sense in this particular case.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the requirement for my homework. I would rather use a while loop but if-else seems to be the requirement. Any idea on how to use the if-else statement?

Comment: @Eliza, this homework seems appropriate, since you seem to confuse a few things. The text says explicitely, that you have to use 6 distinct variables, not an Array. And that you have to use an `if...else` structure not a possible `switch`. And `if...else` and `while` do essentially different things, and are not interchangeable. The one is a **condition** the other one is a **repetition**

Comment: And whatever attempt here you choose to go for. make sure that you *really* understand it, and can explain every char or sign and its purpose to your teacher. Because I doubt that you'd really understand how exactly the `~~` part in something like `~~(Math.random() * 6)+1` works. Bit operations will be a later lesson, and this one in particular is kind of a hack.

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce another variable for a [random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) value between equal or greater than 0 and smaller than 6 and use it as index for the counting array.

Then you need a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), for counting the distribution of 60000 random values.

```js
var array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    i,
    r;
    
for (i = 0; i < 60000; i++) {          // iterate 60000 times
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // generate random value
    array[r]++;                        // increment counter
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be a *homework*, since you **have** to use `if..else`.

However, you don't need to use a `if...else` for this:

```js
var arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0];

for(var i = 0; i < 60000; i++){
  arr[~~(Math.random()*6)]++; 
};

console.log(arr)
```

**Explanation**

The code has an `for` loop, which starts at 0 and ends at 60,000:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 60000; i++){
    //...
};
```

For each iteration, a random value from 0 to 6 is generated...

```
Math.random()*6
```

... and converted to an integer using `~~`.

Then, the element in the array at that random position is incremented:

```
arr[~~(Math.random()*6)]++;
```

## Homework

Since this is in fact [a homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745434/rolling-a-die-60-000-times-using-if-else-if#comment72607933_42745434) and your requirements are:

1. Six variables
2. A six-way `if..else`

You can use this ugly, cumbersome and awkward code:

```js
var one = two = three = four = five = six = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 60000; i++) {
  var random = ~~(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  if (random === 1) {
    one++
  } else if (random === 2) {
    two++
  } else if (random === 3) {
    three++
  } else if (random === 4) {
    four++
  } else if (random === 5) {
    five++
  } else if (random === 6) {
    six++
  }
};

var arr = [one, two, three, four, five, six];

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: "_I'm new to javascript_" A "one-liner" without any explanation won't help her...

Answer (score 1):

`for`, `Math.random`:

```js
var freqs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var freqsLength = freqs.length; //* save array length into variable for more productivity
var rolls = 6000; //* how many time we want to roll dice

for(var i = 0; i < rolls; i++) { //* start rolling in loop
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * freqsLength); //* get ramdom value
  freqs[j]++; //* save freq result
}
alert(freqs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
function randBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

let counters = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0};

for (let i = 0; i < 60000; i++) {
  counters[randBetween(1, 6)]++;
}

console.log(counters);
```

And here's what I'm guessing your teacher wants:

```
function randBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}

let one = 0;
let two = 0;
let three = 0;
let four = 0;
let five = 0;
let six = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 60000; i++) {
  const n = randBetween(1, 6);
  if (n === 1) { one++; }
  else if (n === 2) { two++; }
  else if (n === 3) { three++; }
  else if (n === 4) { four++; }
  else if (n === 5) { five++; }
  else { six++; }
}

console.log(one, two, three, four, five, six);
```

You can decide for yourself which you think is the superior solution (Hint: How would you change each example to reflect rolling of a 100 sided die?)

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example with if-else:

```js
var array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var randomNumber;
    
for (var i = 0; i < 60000; i++) {   
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if(randomNumber === 1){
      array[0]++;
    }
    else if(randomNumber === 2){
      array[1]++;
    }
    else if(randomNumber === 3){
      array[2]++;
    }
    else if(randomNumber === 4){
      array[3]++;
    }
    else if(randomNumber === 5){
      array[4]++;
    }
    else if(randomNumber === 6){
      array[5]++;
    }
}

console.log(array);
```